# HTML CSS, animated background that pauses when user stops scrolling

Tags: css, html

I'm aware of parallax backgrounds and images that change when a user scrolls past a div or another object, but what is the name - if the concept exists (I haven't seen it in the wild yet) - of a web page background that is animated when a user is scrolling down a page and stops/pauses when they stop scrolling?

For example, imagine Waterfina makes bottled water. Their page loads and the background shows a full 20oz bottle of water. As the user scrolls down the page, the bottle empties.

Comment: Are you try `background-attachment: fixed;`?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I'm not sure of the vocabulary or if that particular scenario I described exists.